# Azure Table storage read and update items in one transaction

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

Is there any way in table storage to read and then update a record? For example in SQL server I would use a query like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET
    testValue = 1
OUTPUT
    inserted.columnA,
    inserted.columnB,
    inserted.columnC
WHERE
    testValue = 0
```

Currently my code looks like this:

```
var filter = "testValue eq 0";
var rangeQuery = new TableQuery<AzStorageEntityAdapter<T>>().Where(filter);

var result = _cloudTable.ExecuteQuery(rangeQuery);

var azStorageEntities = result.ToList();
IList<T> results = azStorageEntities.Select(r => r.InnerObject).ToList();
```

Is there some way to add a update clause along with my where clause when it reads the values that meet the filters criteria that 'testValue' is also updated to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible in a single operation.

You must first fetch an entity (1st operation), update it and then save it back in the table (2nd operation).